# Port forwarding not working in Fritzbox

Tags: internet, port-forwarding, webserver, port, fritzbox

I want to expose a tiny web server developed in python using flask package.

I run it on my local machine using

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

which starts the server locally on port 5000 which it is accessible locally & over my LAN network.

Then I am logging into the rooter in fritz.box , &

- assign my device a static network
- enable independent port forwarding to my device
- enable port forwarding for my device to port 5000 + exposing host over the internet.

However after doing this I can't reach the server using :port

Comment: Where are you trying to access it from? Inside or outside your home network? Once you've routed it through from the outside world, you can only access it from inside if the router supports [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning).

Comment: From inside the network (using 192.168... ) it works. I'm actually doing this for testing that my router is opening the ports properly

Comment: If you're accessing it at a local IP address, 192.168.x.x that is not a valid test. From inside *or* outside you need to be able to access it at its *public* IP address. See my hairpinning link.

Comment: I'm just trying to check whether the port is open or not with https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ Port opening seems not to be working. What could it went wrong? Does the provider need to provide me with an IP or smth?

Comment: There's not enough information to work with.